# Unable to create temporary file

Tags: macos, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have selenium web-driver test set up which looks like -

```
startBrowserBeforeTestMethod
testMethod1
testMethod2
quitBrowserAfterTestMethod
```

Test execution works well for first test method and I see browser profile being created in `/private/var/folders/9n/16qzc0qx55v5r981zjndpytw0000gn/T`
and is wiped out when quitting the browser

But browser instantiation fails before second test method with following error -

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unable to create temporary file at /var/folders/9n/16qzc0qx55v5r981zjndpytw0000gn/T/<Test_Name>-1524821528250-0
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1cd5757287168e54b817830adce9b0158d', time: '2016-06-30 19:26:09'
System info: host: 'Taruns-MBP', ip: '192.168.2.105', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.12.6', java.version: '1.7.0_79'
Driver info: driver.version: ScreenShotWebDriver
```

Not an avid mac user and have not seen such issue on linux. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unable to create temporary file at /var/folders/9n/16qzc0qx55v5r981zjndpytw0000gn/T/<Test_Name>-1524821528250-0
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1cd5757287168e54b817830adce9b0158d', time: '2016-06-30 19:26:09'
System info: host: 'Taruns-MBP', ip: '192.168.2.105', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.12.6', java.version: '1.7.0_79'
Driver info: driver.version: ScreenShotWebDriver
```

...implies that *WebDriverException* was raised while trying to create a temporary folder at `/var/folders/9n/16qzc0qx55v5r981zjndpytw0000gn/T/*`

However your main issue is the **version compatibility** between the binaries you are using as follows :

- Your *Selenium Client* version is **2.53.1** of **2016-06-30 19:26:09** which is almost **2 years** older.
- Your *JDK version* is **1.7.0_79** which is pretty **ancient**.

So there is a clear mismatch between the *JDK v7u79* , *Selenium Client v2.53.1* and the *Hardware/Software* configuration you are using.

### Solution

- Ensure that `/var/folders/` have executable permission (`chmod 777`) for non-root users.
- Upgrade *JDK* to  recent levels [**JDK 8u162**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u162-relnotes-4021436.html).
- Upgrade *Selenium* to  current levels [**Version 3.11.0**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *test Suite*.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test` as a non-root user.

Comment: About jdk and selenium client version, I can not migrate to java8 for now hence stuck with older version.

Why does not permission issue show up on first test run? First test run succeeds but second  test run fails with unable to create file error

Comment: @Tarun Incase your coding pattern is restricted to _Java 7_ coding style you will be through. But incase your program includes _Java 8_ coding style your program will break. You need to revisit exactly at which line your program breaks and if needed convert the _Java 8_ coding style to _Java 7_ coding style.

Comment: hmm why are we talking about java7/8. The question I posted is about test run failure only for second test run which does not seem related to java7/8. Is not it?